# What does "as nearly as" means?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Could you please explain the phrase "as nearly as could be discerned" in the following passage?

> Suddenly Hewitt touched his companion's arm and pointed toward the
> window. A faint rustling sound was perceptible, and, **as nearly as**
> could be discerned in the darkness, some white blind or covering was
> placed over the glass from the inside. Arthur Morrison, *Martin
> Hewitt, Investigator*

Does this mean "as far as they could discern"?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. The following do mean essentially the same thing:

> as nearly as could be discerned
> as far as they could discern

You'll note that the novel was published in 1894. Most experienced readers will agree that the style of this phrase is quite old-fashioned in fiction. Contemporary writers seldom use it unless they are going for a historical atmosphere.

Comment: I might well use it. Someone: Is Grandfather alive? Me: As far as I can tell.

Comment: It is literary yes, it is not old fashioned at all.